# The total number of games played in chess tournament

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are two women participating in a chess tournament.
>   Every participant played two games with the other participants.
>   The number of games that the men played between themselves
>   proved to exceed by 66 the number of games that the men 
>   played with the women.Find the total number of games played 
>   in tournament.

$a.)\ 132\\
b.)\ 112\\
c.)\ 156\\
\color{green}{d.)\ 210} $

Let the number of men be $x$.

$2\dbinom{x}{2}=4x+66 \\
\implies x=11 $

Total games played = $2\dbinom{11+2}{2}=156$.

But the answer given in book is $d.)\ 210 .$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: What if the women played with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Your translation of the problem is not correct.  Letting $x$ be the number of men and $y$ the number of women, then the men played $2{x \choose 2} = x(x-1)$ games among themselves.  The men played $2xy$ games with the women, so you need $x(x-1)=2xy+66$  If you multiply by $\frac 1x$ you get $x-1=2y+\frac {66}x$, so $x$ must divide $66$.  Try the factors and see what you get.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2xy$ games played between a man and a woman and $2\binom x2$ games played between two men?

Comment: @CameronBuie:  I missed the two games between each pair.  Thanks.

Comment: Solving that equation should indeed yield $x=11$ (or $x=-6,$ which is nonsense), though.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I am getting $x=11$ from your equation, how should I proceed now?

Comment: @RK:  Then the tournament has $13$ players, who play $2{13\choose 2}=156$ games.  I agree with you that the book is wrong.

Comment: I too agree the book is wrong, as we can cross-check that $156$ is obtained also by adding the M/M games $(2{11\choose 2})$ plus the W/W games $(2)$ plus the M/W games $(4\cdot 11)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may look it as a graph $G=(V,E)$ fully connected with some $V$ which is the number of players.

Let $E$ be the relations between players.

Let $E'$ be the relations between the men.

Let also $C$ be the games between men and women.

We simply note that we form $ E = E' + C + 1 $, since the edges are the ones connecting the men, the edges between the men and women and the edge between both women. We know that $ C = 2(V-2) $ as well as $ E = \frac{V(V-1)}{2} $. Solving returns $ V = 13 $. The total relations we have is $ E = \frac{(13) \  (12)}{2} $.
Then the number of games is $ \text{games} = (13)(12) = 156 $.

---

The image shows the graph. The women are the nodes $A$ and $D$. The group of edges $C$ is the now shown. The missing edge between the women is omitted because it isn't considered when comparing $C$ and $E'$.

[image: graph]

Tell me if you think I made an error somewhere.

---

Checking back (because I doubted it too), let's try with $210 \text{ games}$.

$$
210 \text{ games} \implies V = 15
$$

So working with that:

$$
C = 2(15-2) = 26 \\
E = E' + C + 1 = (26 + 33) + 26 + 1 = 86 \implies V \neq 15
$$